# Excel Add "Format As Date" to Quick Access Bar

Tags: excel

I would like a button added to the Quick Access Toolbar that automatically formats the selected cells as a Date.  I copy and paste dates in all the time then have to hit CTRL-1 and select date format to get them to display well.

Now that I think about it I would like a short-cut key like CTRL-SHIFT-1 to automatically do this.

Thanks

Comment: what's the date format? and what about recording a macro and assigning a combination of keys to it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro that I use for this purpose:

```
Sub uDate()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "dddd, dd mmmm yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

naturally you can modify the date format to suit your needs.